# Android Image uploading Getting Error

Tags: android

While i selecting the image from gallery and uploading image to the server..I getting error like these But it didn't get force close..

Actually the prob arises not wen i upload the image..It came while i choosing from gallery..

Error

> Activity com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity$1@41032458 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
>
> android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity$1@41032458 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?

Answer (score 0):

ChooserActivity  has a Broadcast Receiver which has not been unregistered, Before uploading and onDestroy unregistered the  Broadcast Receiver

Comment: does this answer solve the purpose, or else i will delete it, kindly comment me with it.

Comment: Its almost mid night here i am just waiting to resolve your issue

Comment: I dont have any broadcast receiver..I adding 3 imagess from the gallery and uploading to the server.

Comment: My answer is wrong, Are you using AsyncTask to upload the image

Comment: i have to delete the answer so others might help you but i am just keeping it to chat with you..

Comment: No one can answer you question only with exception because it gives only assumption what might have happened please post the code

Comment: I cant upload my code..It is too large file .. Then i dont know y you are urging to delete the post

Comment: I am going to delete my post not yours

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25015/discussion-between-coder-and-ranjith)

Comment: when other people see's it, they will think it has been answered and you might be delayed in getting the help